# Funnel visualisation vs Reverse goal path

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, goal-tracking

I manage an e-commerce and I created 10 different goals on Google Analytics - all of them with "destination" that "equals to" the URL of purchase completed.

Also I created for all the goals, the funnel that starts from the welcome page after registering on the website and ends with the purchase completed URL.
The difference between these funnels is just one step which indicates the payment method used.

Why the final conversion numbers are totally different from the conversions shown in "reverse goal path"?
This latter section actually shows a more realistic scenario.
What am I missing?